# How to Handle ..Unhandled 'error' event in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am getting below error and I also know that it is throwing because the `server.log` file does not exist.

But what I want to know is how to handle this error programmatically like we do for `unCaughtException` e.g

```
process.on('unCaughtException', function(err){
    logger.error(err1)
})
```

Below is the error, I am getting:

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '../logs/server.log'
at Error (native)
```

Below is the actual code ..that is throwing this error.

```
module.exports = new winston.Logger({
transports: [
new winston.transports.File({
  level: 'info',
  filename: '../logs/server.log',
  json: false,
  maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
  maxFiles: 2,
  colorize: false
}),
new winston.transports.Console({
  level: 'debug',
  json: false,
  colorize: true
})
],
exitOnError: false
});
```

Comment: unCaughtException event name is wrong, uncaughtException is the right name. (this is a comment, not an aswer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your code, you're using an event emitter that is emitting an `error` event when errors happen, in which case you need to listen for those events:

```
someLibrary({ logfile : '../logs/server.log' }).on('error', function(err) {
  ...handle the error...
});
```

More info [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_error_events).

**EDIT**: in the specific situation of Winston, you should attach an `error` event handler to the transport instance:

```
module.exports = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: 'info',
      filename: '../logs/server.log',
      json: false,
      maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
      maxFiles: 2,
      colorize: false
    }).on('error', function(err) {
      console.error(err.stack);
    }),
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: 'debug',
      json: false,
      colorize: true
    })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks robert for quick suggestion...yes I am using winston moudle to configure logger

Comment: @Vikash check out [this documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#exceptions) about Winston-specifics (although I wonder if that applies to errors thrown by Winston itself).

Comment: I gone through the link u shared...will try for sure..but that looks more for handling exception ..not the error...is there not any other easy way to handle this...

Comment: In below link... https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#events-and-callbacks-in-winston...As given, I tried ....logger.on('error', function (err) { /* Do Something */ }); but this did not work